# How can I access elements in Object?

Tags: solidity, web3js, metamask

I have my contract object and this has attributes like

```
contract.balanceOf
contract.myDividends
contract.totalSupply
contract.myTokens
```

I get an error this._eth.call is not a function when i try to call them like this

```
  contract.balanceOf(accounts, function ( error) {
        $('#account-balance').html = balance;
     });



contract.buy
contract.sell
contract.withdraw
contract.reinvest
```

For above calls i get this error

```
inpage.js:1 Uncaught Error: Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function
    at Object.InvalidNumberOfSolidityArgs (inpage.js:1)
    at u.validateArgs (inpage.js:1)
    at u.toPayload (inpage.js:1)
    at u.sendTransaction (inpage.js:1)
    at u.execute (inpage.js:1)
```

Please have a look at my code ond tell me what i do wrong
https://pastebin.com/wAsCeNTG

Comment: What is your web3 library version? You can find this out by running in the terminal npm view web3 version.

Comment: Version = 1.2.5-rc.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm able to execute **balanceOf** and **sell** methods like this:

```
const contract = web3.eth.contract(abi).at(address);

window.addEventListener('load', async function() {
    // Wait for loading completion to avoid race conditions with web3 injection timing.
    var web3;
    var globalState = {};

    console.log(web3, 'web3');
    if(window.ethereum) {
        web3 = new Web3(window['ethereum']);
        try {
            // Request account access if needed
            await window.ethereum.enable();

            web3.eth.getAccounts(function (error, accounts) {
                document.getElementById('account-address').innerHTML = accounts[0];
            });

            // Acccounts now exposed
            window.ethereum.on('accountsChanged', function () {
                web3.eth.getAccounts(function (error, accounts) {
                    document.getElementById('account-address').innerHTML = accounts[0];
                });

                window.ethereum.on('connect', function () {
                    //    console.log('connect');
                });
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    } else if (window.web3) {
        console.log(2);
        // Legacy dapp browsers...
        // Use Mist/MetaMask's provider.
        const web3 = window.web3;
    } else {
        console.log(3);
        // Fallback to localhost; use dev console port by default...
        const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/9bee77f147884c73bb2852e269dacece');
        web3 = new Web3(provider);
    }

    // get token balance of current account
    function balanceOf() {
        web3.eth.getAccounts(function (error, accounts) {
            contract.balanceOf(accounts[0], function(err, result) {
                if(err) {
                    console.log(err, 'err');
                } else {
                    console.log(parseInt(result), 'result');
                }
            });
        });
    }
    balanceOf();

    // sell method
    function sell() {
        web3.eth.getAccounts(function (error, accounts) {
            contract.sell(555, {from: accounts[0], gas: 250000}, function(err, result) {
                if(err) {
                    console.log(err, 'err');
                } else {
                    console.log(parseInt(result), 'result');
                }
            });
        });
    }
    sell();
});
```

The rest methods you can create them by your just watch out for passing the correct parameters to the functions.

Comment: Thanks, balanceOf works but it doesnt update when address is changed and about the sell button i worry about a bit later- there are so many things that ar confusing to me with this stupid ethereum web3- but thanks.

Comment: everythign i try myself i get some errors i never seen before and all those functions dont work either- i tried the same code for totalAGIBalance etc- this ethereum is some bullshit- this is unbelievable

Comment: @CodingJoe the update balance is not happening on account change, because you are not doing this logic at method which is listening for account change. I think you should dive a bit more into javascript basics and event handlers so you can build you dApp applications easier.

Comment: i can get all these calls now to work in the console - but what i dont understand is why can i not access these variables like current logged in account?